# how to create a fixed floating button on top right of textarea

Tags: html, css

I want to write something like the following:

```
|------------------------------------------------------|</br>
|td                                                    |
| |--------------------------------------------------| |
| |textarea                          floating button | |
| |                                                  | |
| |                                                  | |
| |                                                  | |
| |                                                  | |
| |                                                  | |
| |--------------------------------------------------| |
|------------------------------------------------------|
```

the outter is td element, and textarea is inside. I want a fixed floating button on the right top corner of textarea, or td. And this textarea and td is behind of this floating button. I tried to use z-index to do that, but didn't work.

Also the button is a dropdown menu.

Can someone tell me how to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: @SpaceBeers is right! but if you put a button over the textarea, this will cover the text that you write inside

Comment: @MCSI true - but that could be fixed by adding padding to textarea http://jsfiddle.net/e2Ggm/1/

Comment: is true @ptriek, but in my opinion, I dont like the space that the padding lefts there, only my opinion! ;)

Comment: @MCSI I am gonna make the button half transparent, and solid while onmouseover. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll be able to do this by giving the outer container *position: relative;* and then the inner elements:

```
position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px;
```

You can then 'layer' them with z-index.

Just because I lost out on 6 points by not including a JSFiddle - here's a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/WYrwf/

Comment: You are right. Thanks. Btw, why there is no line breaks when I copy the plain text image I drew in text eidtor into stackoverflow.

Answer (score 8):

Or to see Spacebeers solution in action :-)

http://jsfiddle.net/e2Ggm/

Comment: Hehe, it's a fast-paced world out here :-)